# How to transfer (sum up) the counts from a set of ranges to ranges that are englobing those ranges?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, bioinformatics

I am working with sequencing data, but I think the problem applies to different range-value datatypes.
I want to combine several experiments of read counts(values) from a set DNA regions that have a start and end position (ranges), into added up counts for other set of DNA regions, which generally englobe many of the primary regions. Like in the following example:

Giving the following table A with ranges and counts:

```
feature start end count1 count2 count3
gene1   1     10  100    30     22
gene2   15    40  20     10     6
gene3   50    70  40     11     7
gene4   100   150 23     15     9
```

and the following table B (with new ranges):

```
feature  start  end
range1   1      45
range2   55     160
```

I would like to get the following count table with the new ranges:

```
feature  start  end  count1  count2  count3
range1   1      45   120     40      28
range2   55     160  63      26      16
```

Just to simplify, if there is at least some overlap (at least a fraction a feature in table A is contained in feature in table B), it should be added up. Any idea of a tool available doing that or a script in perl, python or R? I am counting the sequencing reads with bedtools multicov, but as far as I searched there is no other functionality doing what I want. Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: pyranges.multioverlap can take a set of ranges to count overlaps in: https://pyranges.readthedocs.io/en/latest/autoapi/pyranges/multioverlap/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply()` and `pd.concat()` with a custom function where `a` corresponds to your first dataframe and `b` corresponds to your second dataframe:

```
def find_englobed(x):

    englobed = a[(a['start'].between(x['start'], x['end'])) | (a['end'].between(x['start'], x['end']))]

    return englobed[['count1','count2','count3']].sum()

pd.concat([b, b.apply(find_englobed, axis=1)], axis=1)
```

Yields:

```
  feature  start  end  count1  count2  count3
0  range1      1   45     120      40      28
1  range2     55  160      63      26      16
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do this by:

1. Creating an artificial `key` column
2. Perform an `outer` join `(mxn)`
3. Filter on the `start` OR `end` value being between our `ranges`
4. [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on `feature` and `sum` the `count` columns
5. Finally `concat` the output to `df2`, to get desired output

```
df1['key'] = 'A'
df2['key'] = 'A'

df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2, on='key', how='outer')

df4 = df3[(df3.start_x.between(df3.start_y, df3.end_y)) | (df3.end_x.between(df3.start_y, df3.end_y))]

df5 = df4.groupby('feature_y').agg({'count1':'sum',
                                    'count2':'sum',
                                    'count3':'sum'}).reset_index()

df_final = pd.concat([df2.drop(['key'], axis=1), df5.drop(['feature_y'], axis=1)], axis=1)
```

**output**

```
print(df_final)
  feature  start  end  count1  count2  count3
0  range1      1   45     120      40      28
1  range2     55  160      63      26      16
```

Answer (score 0):

If it can help somebody, based on @rahlf23 answer, I modified it to make it more general, considering that on one side, the counting columns can be more, and that besides the range, it is also important to be on the right chromosome.

So if table "a" is:

```
feature Chromosome  start   end count1  count2  count3
gene1   Chr1        1       10  100     30      22
gene2   Chr1        15      40  20      10      6
gene3   Chr1        50      70  40      11      7
gene4   Chr1        100     150 23      15      9
gene5   Chr2        5       30  24      17      2
gene5   Chr2        40      80  4       28     16
```

and table "b" is:

```
feature Chromosome  start   end
range1  Chr1        1       45
range2  Chr1        55      160
range3  Chr2        10      90
range4  Chr2        100     200
```

with the following python script:

```
import pandas as pd

def find_englobed(x):
    englobed = a[(a['Chromosome'] == x['Chromosome']) & (a['start'].between(x['start'], x['end']) | (a['end'].between(x['start'], x['end'])))]
    return englobed[list(a.columns[4:])].sum()

pd.concat([b, b.apply(find_englobed, axis=1)], axis=1)
```

Now with `a['Chromosome'] == x['Chromosome'] &` I ask for them to be in the same Chromosome, and with `list(a.columns[4:])` I get all the columns from the 5th until the end, being independent on the number of count columns.

I obtain the following result:

```
feature Chromosome  start   end count1  count2  count3
range1  Chr1        1       45  120.0   40.0    28.0
range2  Chr1        55      160 63.0    26.0    16.0
range3  Chr2        10      90  28.0    45.0    18.0
range4  Chr2        100     200 0.0     0.0     0.0
```

I am not sure why the obtained counts are with floating points.. any comment?

Comment: Just use `.astype(int)` for those columns

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing genomics in pandas you might want to look into [pyranges](https://github.com/biocore-ntnu/pyranges):

```
import pyranges as pr

c = """feature Chromosome  Start   End count1  count2  count3
gene1   Chr1        1       10  100     30      22
gene2   Chr1        15      40  20      10      6
gene3   Chr1        50      70  40      11      7
gene4   Chr1        100     150 23      15      9
gene5   Chr2        5       30  24      17      2
gene5   Chr2        40      80  4       28     16
"""

c2 = """feature Chromosome  Start   End
range1  Chr1        1       45
range2  Chr1        55      160
range3  Chr2        10      90
range4  Chr2        100     200 """

gr, gr2 = pr.from_string(c), pr.from_string(c2)

j = gr2.join(gr).drop(like="_b")
# +------------+--------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
# | feature    | Chromosome   |     Start |       End |    count1 |    count2 |    count3 |
# | (object)   | (category)   |   (int32) |   (int32) |   (int64) |   (int64) |   (int64) |
# |------------+--------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------|
# | range1     | Chr1         |         1 |        45 |       100 |        30 |        22 |
# | range1     | Chr1         |         1 |        45 |        20 |        10 |         6 |
# | range2     | Chr1         |        55 |       160 |        40 |        11 |         7 |
# | range2     | Chr1         |        55 |       160 |        23 |        15 |         9 |
# | range3     | Chr2         |        10 |        90 |        24 |        17 |         2 |
# | range3     | Chr2         |        10 |        90 |         4 |        28 |        16 |
# +------------+--------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
# Unstranded PyRanges object has 6 rows and 7 columns from 2 chromosomes.
# For printing, the PyRanges was sorted on Chromosome.

df = j.df

fs = {"Chromosome": "first", "Start":
      "first", "End": "first", "count1": "sum", "count2": "sum", "count3": "sum"}
result = df.groupby("feature".split()).agg(fs)
#         Chromosome  Start  End  count1  count2  count3
# feature
# range1        Chr1      1   45     120      40      28
# range2        Chr1     55  160      63      26      16
# range3        Chr2     10   90      28      45      18
```